# shell variable value not storing inside file

Tags: linux, shell-scripting

I wrote following script, which generate random password and  store it in file

```
pass1=</dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9|head -c8
echo $pass1
echo "$pass1" >/tmp/a
```

Above script printing generated password through "echo $pass1" command. But nothing getting stored inside created /tmp/a file .

Please let me know whats wrong i am doing.

Comment: Are you missing a pipe between `urandom` and `tr`?

Comment: @jscott, this is a [unique usage of the `<` operator](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40837/bash-linux-random-cli-password-generator-and)

Comment: @MikePennington Thanks for that, I was trying to work through the syntax and what the expected output is... Both the OP's and your examples produce `tr` errors for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to store the password in an intermediate variable.  You only need this line in your shell script

```
</dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9|head -c8 > /tmp/a
```

I saved as `foo.sh`, made permissions 755, and executed it under linux...

```
[mpenning@chestnut ~]$ uname -a
Linux chestnut.he.net 2.6.32.46-1-grsec #1 SMP Fri Sep 2 12:42:23 PDT 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[mpenning@chestnut ~]$ ./foo.sh
[mpenning@chestnut ~]$ cat /tmp/a
qAUezN0-[mpenning@chestnut ~]$
```

Comment: This gives me:
`tr: write error: Broken pipe`
`tr: write error`

Comment: hmm works in cygwin and linux... see my edit

Comment: Thanks , this worked for me </dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9|head -c8 > /tmp/a

Comment: Oh my, I'm still getting the `tr` errors, yet `/tmp/a` is created and contains the expected data.  Odd, must be something screwy in my shell. +1

Comment: @vnix27, FYI... there is also the `mkpasswd` command on most linux systems, but I like the control `tr` gives me